# Need to load isometric tile map using Flutter Flame without tile layers overlapping each other?

Tags: flutter, tiled, flame

- Current bug behavior - (https://prnt.sc/AZt3-gBovXLw)
  There is a strange overlapping issue occurring at the time of rendering the map. I am using embedded tilesets and external as well. I have tried all the encodings(Base64, CSV), but still facing the same. The map is isometric with 256*128 tile size.
- This is my map properties - (https://prnt.sc/tz_KIRzQf8vG)
- Steps to reproduce
  You will need to load isometric tilesets of 256*128 px size. Connect with me if you want the files.
- Flutter doctor output
  `[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.6, on macOS 13.4.1 22F770820d darwin-arm64,
  locale en-IN)
  • Flutter version 3.10.6 on channel stable at
  /Users/ayaanpathan/Desktop/Development/FlutterSDK/flutter
  • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
  • Framework revision f468f3366c (11 days ago), 2023-07-12 15:19:05 -0700
  • Engine revision cdbeda788a
  • Dart version 3.0.6
  • DevTools version 2.23.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
• Android SDK at /Users/ayaanpathan/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.0
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android
Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Build 14E300c
• CocoaPods version 1.12.0

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
 https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.76.2)
• VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
• Flutter extension version 3.60.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
• macOS (desktop) • macos  • darwin-arm64   • macOS 13.4.1 22F770820d
darwin-arm64
• Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 114.0.5735.198

[✓] Network resources
• All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!`

- More environment information
  `Create a list of more environment information, like:

Flame version: 1.8.0
Flame tiled version: 1.12.0
Platform affected: android, ios, web
Platform version affected: tested on android 12, iOS 16 and web`

- Expected behavior - (https://prnt.sc/AZt3-gBovXLw)
  I need to render the map exactly the same how it looks on tiled software.

Below are the points I've tried yet.

- I've tried loading the same .tmx file with unity game engine, it's working fine on unity.
- I've created the map in orthogonal in tiled and tried to render in Flutter Flame, but facing same overlapping issue.
- Tried with multiple different tile size, like 64*32, 32*16.

Below is the package I've tried till now for map rendering.

- flame_tiled